# How to include a list of libraries to be added to jar from an external file

Tags: java, ant

In our project we have use a lot of external libraries and these are partially added to different builds.
Currently this list is specified for each product in an external file using:

```
    <!DOCTYPE project [<!ENTITY ext_jar_list SYSTEM "../common/libs_64.xml">]>
```

and later included into jar export step using

```
<fileset dir="${bin}">
</fileset>
&ext_jar_list;
```

This external file has following format:

```
...
<zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="${lib1}/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar"/>
<zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="${lib1}/ojdbc6.jar"/>
...
```

This is working very well.

I would like to do it a different way, namely have a common parent ant script and only provide this list of external jars and main class in newly created jar from children ants. 
But the first part doesn't work for me. I have tried to define path to this external file in sub-ant

```
<property name="lib_files_folder"   value="${demo}/buildscripts/common"/>
<property name="lib_files_file"     value="libs_64.xml"/>
```

and include it to parent ant

```
<fileset dir="${lib_files_folder}"/>
    <include name="${lib_files_folder}/${lib_files_file}"/>
    <!-- Or simply -->
    <include name="${lib_files_file}"/>
<fileset/>
```

But I only got:

```
deploy_common_ant.xml:111: No directory specified for fileset.
```

or

```
deploy_common_ant.xml:111: ...\libs_64.xml is not a directory.
```

If I specify

```
<!DOCTYPE project [<!ENTITY ext_jar_list SYSTEM "../common/libs_64.xml">]>
```

in sub-ant but not in parent ant, I get:

```
The entity "ext_jar_list" was referenced, but not declared.
```

Is there any way to include these jars from this file as a parameter properly?

Thanks.